# Randomise multiple times and auto render

Tags: python, rendering, color

I am looking at how I can edit this so that it randomises the colours in that colour ramp, then renders it out then repeats the process automatically. Say 100 times, producing different results each time.

Is that possible?[nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULWDp.png)
[image]

Comment: You can plug a white noise node in between the random and the color ramp, set it to 4D and set your script to change the w value after every render

Comment: Do you to "shuffle" the colors, or are you trying to change the colors of the color ramp itself (creating entirely new colors)?

Answer (score 0):

I found a video for you on YouTube: https://youtu.be/a2vhQ6GfXIw
Just skip the video untill 52:50 at that moment you can see how it works.
Have a nice modelling day!!!

Greetings,
Rookie modeller Sjondepon